# Detect if Android device uses navigational control

Tags: android

This is something I've been struggling with for quite some time. A lot of Chinese Android manufacturers create Android TV boxes that are controlled using a remote with keypad controls.

**I'm looking for a definitive way of detecting if the device uses navigational controls** or if it is in fact using touch screen input. Certain devices might emulate touch screen input as mouse input as well, so it's kind of tricky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Jozua's answer, I created this simple method which can be used to determine if a device uses navigation controls from a number of factors. The code is written in a way that attempts to fail early.

```
/**
 * Determines if the device uses navigation controls as the primary navigation from a number of factors.
 * @param context Application Context
 * @return True if the device uses navigation controls, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean usesNavigationControl(Context context) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (configuration.navigation == Configuration.NAVIGATION_NONAV) {
        return false;
    } else if (configuration.touchscreen == Configuration.TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER) {
        return false;
    } else if (configuration.navigation == Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD) {
        return true;
    } else if (configuration.touchscreen == Configuration.TOUCHSCREEN_NOTOUCH) {
        return true;
    } else if (configuration.touchscreen == Configuration.TOUCHSCREEN_UNDEFINED) {
        return true;
    } else if (configuration.navigationHidden == Configuration.NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES) {
        return true;
    } else if (configuration.uiMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tested this on numerous phones, tablets, emulator configurations and Google TV. A number of devices are controlled using a remote control and a USB mouse. I haven't yet tested whether it works as expected on such devices.

Answer (score 2):

Please read about input controls in the following articles:

- http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/tv/optimizing-navigation-tv.html

To see at run-time what types of navigation a user has available, use the [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) class.

```
Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
if (Configuration.NAVIGATION_NONAV == configuration.navigation) {
    // Device has no navigation facility other than using the touchscreen.
} else if (Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD == configuration.navigation) {
    // Device has a directional-pad (d-pad) for navigation.
} else if (Configuration.NAVIGATION_TRACKBALL == configuration.navigation) {
    // Device has a trackball for navigation.
} // ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I forgot about the Configuration class :-) I posted another answer with working code that takes a number of cases into consideration.